# didBeginContact doesn't fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Any idea why my didBeginContact method is never firing? The sphere and rectangles are actually touching each other...

Here i declare the two categories

```
static const uint32_t rectangleCategory = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t ballCategory = 0x1 << 1;
```

This method creates a sphere

```
- (SKSpriteNode *)createSphereNode
{
SKSpriteNode *sphereNode =
[[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"sphere.png"];

sphereNode.name = @"sphereNode";
sphereNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
sphereNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = rectangleCategory;

return sphereNode;
}
```

This method creates a rectangle

```
- (void) createRectangle
{
SKSpriteNode *rectangle = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"balk.png"];

rectangle.position = CGPointMake(randomBetween(0, self.size.width),
                            self.size.height);
rectangle.name = @"rectangleNode";
rectangle.physicsBody =
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(rectangle.size.width/2)-7];

rectangle.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
rectangle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = rectangleCategory;
rectangle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballCategory;

[self addChild:rectangle];
}
```

This is the didBeginContact method that doesn't fire

```
- (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{

NSLog(@"Contact begin");

SKSpriteNode *firstNode, *secondNode;

firstNode = (SKSpriteNode *)contact.bodyA.node;
secondNode = (SKSpriteNode *) contact.bodyB.node;

if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == rectangleCategory)
    && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ballCategory))
{
    CGPoint contactPoint = contact.contactPoint;

    float contact_x = contactPoint.x;
    float target_x = secondNode.position.x;
    float margin = secondNode.frame.size.height/2 - 25;

    if ((contact_x > (target_x - margin)) &&
        (contact_x < (target_x + margin)))
    {
        NSLog(@"Hit");
        self.score++;
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas? All help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Stijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally suspected it could be the lack of a proper SKPhysicsContactDelegate as it was not mentioned in the original post. Upon inspection of the code however, this was not the case and the problem was simply that the `SKPhysicsBody` used for rectangle was created with the ill-fitting `bodyWithCircleOfRadius:` rather than the `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:`.

```
rectangle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize: rectangle.size];
```

---

Original answer, not correct for this particular case, but leaving it here for anyone with a similar problem down the line:

There is no mention of the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` anywhere to be seen in the code you supply. The `didBeginContact:` method is a delegate method for the `physicsWorld` property of your `SKScene`.

So if you for instance want to have the `SKScene` being its own delegate it must support the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol. e. g.:

```
@interface YourSceneSubclass : NSObject <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```

Then you need to set the delegate somewhere in your scene before the game starts proper...

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is in the didMoveToView method

http://pastebin.com/NUQaZU1e

Comment: ...and it obviously adheres to the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`? ...and the `didBeginContact:` method is in the same class?

Comment: Can you please explain yourself more clear? I'm new to this stuff.

The didBeginContact method is indeed in the same class.

Comment: OK, and you have set the scene to confirm to the delegate like described above? `@interface YourSceneSubclass : NSObject <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>` Any warnings? Are the nodes added to the same scene?

Comment: This is my ArcheryScene.h: http://pastebin.com/bMt2sCvu

This is my ArcheryScene.m: http://pastebin.com/1VpMUupj

I don't have any warnings

Comment: Hm, not able to see any obvious omissions there, but I haven't tried to compile the code. Could it possibly be that the physicsBody are too different from what you observe visually? I'm in particular thinking about the `rectangle.physicsBody =
    [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:(rectangle.size.width/2)-7];` Why not use `bodyWithRectangleOfSize:` instead which matches the rectangle 100%...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47691/discussion-between-nickfalk-and-stijn-hoste)